# Do I need to always use async / await in methods already in async code flow?

Tags: .net, async-await

Let's say I'm already in an async method, and am going to await the results of a nested method:

```
var x = await CallMethodAsync();
```

Then, let’s say you could choose to write CallMethodAsync in either of two ways:

```
public Task<int> CallMethodAsync() {
     var y = DoStuff();
     return _dependency.CallAnotherMethodAsync(y);
 }
```

or:

```
public async Task<int> CallMethodAsync() {
    var y = DoStuff();
    return await _dependency.CallAnotherMethodAsync(y);
}
```

Is there a difference? Is there any point to adding the async / await syntax in the CallMethodAsync method definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is subtle and is largely a trade off between:

- getting slightly different exception semantics if an exception is thrown **before** the asynchronous part of `CallAnotherMethodAsync`
- less overhead (allocations etc) in `CallMethodAsync`

Personally, I would tend *not* to have the `await` here if all of:

- the `return [await]` is the very last operation
- we do not need to transform or inspect the returned value

but it is a slightly subjective scenario. Your choice might also depend on how "hot" this code path is; if it is a high-throughput IO loop, probably avoid the `await`; if it is less high volume: pay the price to get the clearer exception semantics.

Comment: Thanks @Marc. Let's assume that the returned value does need to be inspected then (that's the value 'x' in the top piece of code), would you say that the async/await would be required in that case?

Comment: @SimonGreen yes; you'd have `var foo = await Whatever(); /* TODO check foo */; return foo;`

Comment: Ah, so you're referring to an inspection of the return within the sub method (CallMethodAsync), not the outer method. OK, so no I'm just assuming that the last operation is the CallAnotherMethodAsync() call. The outer method (which is awaiting CallMethodAsync) may then inspect the return. In this case, there's no difference between return await and just return ?

Comment: Just read your edit - so the only advantage you can see is better detail in thrown exceptions?

Comment: @SimonGreen if you don't need to inspect or modify the value, and if it is the final operation; then yes, exception handling is the key difference; note that this also impacts *your* method; if your method isn't `async` (because it doesn't need to be), then exceptions thrown in `CallMethodAsync` will *also* surface slightly differently

Comment: What do you mean by _your_ method? Do you mean the outermost method? If so, then yes I've stipulated that it does need to be async because it is awaiting the call to CallMethodAsync(). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SimonGreen I mean `CallMethodAsync`. If an exception happens, say in `DoStuff();`, then it may surface slightly differently depending on whether `CallMethodAsync` is marked `async` or not